# Insurance claim for cancelled trip due to sickness

Tags: health, insurance, cancellations

I came down with food poisoning a few days ago and was unable to begin my trip (multiple days driving + trains, boats).

I had to cancel the trip literally on the morning I was supposed to leave and choose a different mode of transport (plane vs driving) because I didn't know when I would feel better again and I have to get back because of visa reasons.

I didn't feel well enough to go to the doctors, but do now - as I'm told I will need a medical certificate.

If I'm well again, is the doctor likely to give me a certificate? If not, what kind of recourse do I have with a claim. All the claims I have seen in the past seem to centre around having 1) Medical certificate before cancelling 2) To use the same mode of transport.

Answer (score 3):

You can still see a doctor now, usually there is a time limit of a few days. The doctor just needs to verify that what he/she observes is consistent with your your description of your medical condition preventing you to go on your trip a few days ago. The doctor is not required to prove that you indeed suffered from that specific illness. You may be well now, but sickness usually doesn't last a long time, so there isn't a consistency problem here.

This is still useful for the insurance company, in a case where the insured suffers from some chronic medical problem who likely knew at the time of booking that he might be unfit to travel, would not get compensation.